# Load SVG file with ts functions IONIC 3

Tags: svg, ionic3

I converted a dwg file to svg file. 
Now this svg file I imported it into a html file.

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="false"  scrollY="true" zoom="true" maxZoom="10"> 
     <object id="svg1" data="assets/svgs/file.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="width:400%;"></object>
  </ion-scroll>
```

In the svg file on rectangles i put this :

```
onclick="btnClicked();"
<g id="P2" onclick="btnEvent($event)">
```

And here the problem, the click works but the function `btnClicked()` dosen't works. 
It gives me this error (in the console)

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: btnClicked is not defined
    at SVGGElement.onclick (file.svg:2946)
```

It seems like I have to check if this object is loaded and the call the function?
Something like this ?

```
var elementExists = document.getElementById("svg1");
```

svg1 is the id of object maybe if i check if it's populate with the svg it ll work?
Anyway this is js I ll do it in ts .

Sorry for my english.

**UPDATE**

When the page is ready I have to go inside the svg and listen all ids that starts with PI and capture the click. svgDwg is the id of the object. Now I'm not able to go inside, where is the svg. 
`a.contentDocument` dosen't works.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    var a = document.getElementById("svgDwg");
    console.log(a);

  }
```

Comment: Can you provide file.svg and also how you add listeners.

Comment: When SVGs with interactivity (scripts like yours) are used in data uris and as sources of img - many browsers have various security policies to prevent malicious behavior. I would recommend to embed your SVG inline. Ionic / Angular are quite OK with this approach with just a few nuances.

Comment: depending on your use case I would just: inline the SVG, added ionic's (click)="btnClicked()" on the element you need (rect). If you have difficulty with this - post your snippet and it can be fixed

Comment: I can't add in line, I have something like >150 svgs so I can't, I have to do something like list on all IDS if they are clicked, but I can't import property the svg file @SergeyRudenko . I add some new code

Comment: Try to change `onclick="btnClicked();"` to `(click)="btnClicked()"`

Comment: @Duannx nothing to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer :

If you want to import in your ionic page a file.svg, without use functions like onclick but use something like listener (`.on('click',...`) in jquery), you can use a combination of jquery and [angular-svg-icon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-svg-icon)

Install first jquery and import in your .ts ionic page :

```
$ npm install jquery --save
import * as $ from 'jquery'
```

Then install the plugin angular-svg-icon :
[full description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-svg-icon)

Import your file.svg in your html :

```
<svg-icon src="path/to/file.svg"></svg-icon>
```

Then write some .ts and jquery for your file.svg in **ionViewDidEnter()** function of ionic

This works for me (after 2 days of research)